# Listview Displaying Name space not values from class Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to bind a simple Listview control using the folloiwng

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="292" Height="80">
        <Border Height="60" Width="60" Margin="10,10,0,10">
            <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="180" Height="42" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                       Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="180" Height="14" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       FontSize="9" Opacity="0.49"/>
        </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

    </ListView>
```

But for some reason when I reference my list which is created as such
    using Parse;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
namespace Curo.DataModel
{
    public class curoLists : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public curoLists()
        {

        }
        public curoLists(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, string type)
        {
            this.UniqueId = uniqueId;
            this.Title = title;
            this.Subtitle = subtitle;
            this.Description = description;
            this.ImagePath = imagePath;
            this.Content = content;
            this.Type = type;
        }


        public curoLists(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, String content, bool unread, Int32 status)
        {
            UniqueId = uniqueId;
            Title = title;
            Subtitle = subtitle;
            Description = description;
            ImagePath = imagePath;
            Content = content;
            Unread = unread;
            Status = status;
        }


        private bool _unread;

        private string _title;
        public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }

            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        public string Subtitle { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public string Content { get; private set; }
        public int Status { get; private set; }
        public string Type { get; private set; }

        public string ViewToUse { get; private set; }
        public bool Unread
        {
            get { return _unread; }
            set
            {
                _unread = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Unread");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        public static async Task<curoLists> CreateFromParseObject(ParseObject parseObject)
        {
            return await Task.Run<curoLists>(() =>
            {
                var mlist = new curoLists();

                mlist.Title = parseObject.ObjectId;
                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("name"))
                {
                    mlist.Title = (string)parseObject["name"];
                }


                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("description"))
                {
                    mlist.Description = (string)parseObject["description"];
                }
                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("image"))
                {
                    mlist.ImagePath = (string)parseObject["image"];
                }


                if (parseObject.ContainsKey("type"))
                {
                    string mtype = (string)parseObject["type"];

                    if (mtype == "N")
                    {
                        mlist.Type = "Notes";
                        mlist.ViewToUse = "Notes.Xaml";
                    }
                }
                return mlist;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

It does not display the requested data instead it just displays the folowing. I populate my list in the following mannor

```
  List<curoLists> cLists;
  public  ClientsManage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      PopulatelistAsync();
  }

public async Task PopulatelistAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            curoListsDal _db = new curoListsDal();


            cLists = await _db.GetListsAync();

            listView.ItemsSource = cLists;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

But it just displays the name space and not the data Curo.DataModel.CuroLists. When i debug the data it is def their and correct spelling the only thing it complains about when i compiles is on my constructor i do not have the await command but that would not make the data not appear would it?.

Comment: Have you tried using ObservableCollection<curoLists> instead of List<curoLists>?

Answer (score 0):

ListView is single Column. So you must custom it with GridView. I also add Window_Loaded method with asyn, and own Dal:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Game Name" 
              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Title"  
              DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<curoLists> cLists;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // decorate this method with asyn
    private async void Window_Loaded(
        object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await PopulatelistAsync();
    }

    public async Task PopulatelistAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            curoListsDal _db = new curoListsDal();
            cLists = await _db.GetListsAync();
            listView.ItemsSource = cLists;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}

public class curoListsDal
{
    public async Task<List<curoLists>> GetListsAync()
    {
        return await
            Task.Run<List<curoLists>>(
                () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // long run
                    var result = new List<curoLists>();
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        var mlist = new curoLists(id,
                            "title" + id, "subtitle", "imagePath",
                            "desc", "content", true, 1);
                        result.Add(mlist);
                    }
                    return result;
                });
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: hungndv this is for windows phone not windows !

Comment: I think it work as the same. ListView also has Load event. Subscribe it instead of window_load event. :D

Comment: no as lsitview for windows phones works with the datatemplate tag